# htaccess to redirect all Not Found pages to its Category

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am trying to use htaccess to redirect all Not Found (404) pages to an upper level - Category page. I have thousands of urls, splitted in 10 categories.

I have a real estate classified website and this occures frequently, estates are being rented or sold frequently.

For example let say: www.example.com/page-i33606 is a post published in TestA category. I know the post's TestA category isn't specified anywhere in url link but on page, in breadcrumb header, and obviously in the backend shows is posted under TestA category.

I want this page 301 redirected to www.example.com/testA-category

Is anyone which can help me to achieve this in htaccess?

Comment: Where's your current `.htaccess`? On the other hand, this sounds impossible if the category to redirect to isn't available anywhere in the URL

Comment: That is nothing that should be done on the level of the protocol. This is business logic, it depends on data only available inside your business logic, so you should implement a forwarding from within that.